# Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

I kown of two Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequalities.
The original one, by Vapnik and Chervonenkis,

$$P\left(\sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left |\nu_n(A) - \nu(A) \right | >\varepsilon \right) \leq 8\, S(\mathcal{A},n)\, e^{-n\varepsilon^2/32}$$

and the following (I am not sure whom to credit for - I read it in Devroye,Lugosi *Combinatorial methods in density estimation*)

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \left |\nu_n(A) - \nu(A) \right | \right] \leq 2 \sqrt{\dfrac{\log 2\,S(\mathcal{A},n) + \log 2}{n}}$$

How do they compare?